# Squash commits along with pull request for remote but keep all commits in local

Tags: git

So I want to squash all my minor commits into one feature commit that I have made by the end of the day. But I don't want to lose all these commits locally i.e I don't want to squash it in my local repo as I want to test the feature first.

Comment: So why not test the feature first, then tidy things up with squash and finally push to a remote repository?

Comment: This is what I have been doing so far. But sometimes some bug is found after couple of days when my feature has gone live. So if I have all the commits in my local branch then I can resolve the bug quickly.

Comment: Sagar, as @Martian below describes. You can do whatever you like with your branch. After pull request has been merged back into master, it will leave a merge commit. Which means you still maintain a full branch commit history on your feature branch

Comment: @e.doroskevic I get it what you are saying. What I was doing was squashing the commits in the feat branch, which I think is a wrong practice. Thanks.

Comment: you can revert squashing :) if that's becoming an issue. But you have to be careful since you mess with history

Answer (score 2):

That's why you work on a separate development branch. Once you're done, or now and then during the development, you squash your commits into a single delivery commit which is then pushed to a master branch. You keep all small commits on the development branch.